# Is it possible to have a field name with "by" in it when using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have an entity which looks like that

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Sheep {
    private Slaughter slaughteredBy;
}
```

I want to write a repository method to get all sheeps slaughtered by a given Slaughter:

```
public interface SheepRepository {
    public List<Sheep> findAllBySlaughteredBy(Slaughter slaughter);
}
```

But I get an NoSuchElementException when I call the findAllBySlaughteredBy method:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.bind(CriteriaQueryParameterBinder.java:63)
```

1. Is the exception thrown because I have "by" in my field name?
2. If the first question's answer is yes, do I actually need to rename my field or can I just use another name for my query function on the repository which would solve the issue?

Comment: JPA API imposes no such restriction. "Spring Data JPA" may have a problem with it, but then that is not the JPA API.

Comment: You are right, thanks! Edited title and tags.

Comment: @jod Can you post the fullstacktrace, the problem is not because of `by`. Also, I don't see any mapping `OneToOne` or `ManyToOne` or `Embeddable` etc for `private Slaughter slaughteredBy;` field.

Comment: have +1 for arbitrarily killing animals in examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `public List<Sheep> findBySlaughteredBy(Slaughter slaughter);`

instead of `public List<Sheep> findAllBySlaughteredBy(Slaughter slaughter);`

because there `findAllBy` is not a valid syntax